# Getting error when installing Torch on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, luajit, torch

I am trying to install Torch on my Mac (OS X 10.11 GM) by following the guide on http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html.

However, when I run

```
cd ~/torch; ./install.sh
```

I always get this error:

```
[/Users/Definiter/torch] > ./install.sh
Prefix set to /Users/Definiter/torch/install
Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BC", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
     (maybe you meant: _lj_BC_ISEQV, _lj_BC_IFUNCV , _lj_BC_KSTR , _lj_BC_ISNEP , _lj_BC_MULVN , _lj_BC_ISTC , _lj_BC_ISFC , _lj_BC_NOT , _lj_BC_ISNUM , _lj_BC_UGET , _lj_BC_RET0 , _lj_BC_RET , _lj_BC_DIVVN , _lj_BC_FUNCCW , _lj_BC_FUNCC , _lj_BC_IFUNCF , _lj_BC_JMP , _lj_BC_FORL , _lj_BC_ILOOP , _lj_BC_LOOP , _lj_BC_JITERL , _lj_BC_IFORL , _lj_BC_JFORI , _lj_BC_RETM , _lj_BC_ISNEXT , _lj_BC_ITERN , _lj_BC_FUNCF , _lj_BC_ITERC , _lj_BC_TGETB , _lj_BC_CALLMT , _lj_BC_CALL , _lj_BC_CALLM , _lj_BC_TSETM , _lj_BC_TSETB , _lj_BC_TSETS , _lj_BC_TGETS , _lj_BC_TGETV , _lj_BC_FNEW , _lj_BC_UCLO , _lj_BC_USETP , _lj_BC_USETN , _lj_BC_USETV , _lj_BC_KPRI , _lj_BC_KNUM , _lj_BC_POW , _lj_BC_MODVV , _lj_BC_ADDNV , _lj_BC_MODVN , _lj_BC_SUBVN , _lj_BC_ADDVN , _lj_BC_UNM , _lj_BC_MOV , _lj_BC_ISTYPE , _lj_BC_ISF , _lj_BC_IST , _lj_BC_VARG , _lj_BC_ISEQP , _lj_BC_ISNEN , _lj_BC_ISEQN , _lj_BC_ISNES , _lj_BC_CALLT , _lj_BC_ISGT , _lj_BC_TSETV , _lj_BC_DIVNV , _lj_BC_JFUNCV , _lj_BC_KNIL , _lj_BC_JLOOP , _lj_BC_TDUP , _lj_BC_ADDVV , _lj_BC_SUBVV , _lj_BC_IITERL , _lj_BC_TSETR , _lj_BC_ISNEV , _lj_BC_ISGE , _lj_BC_FORI , _lj_BC_USETS , _lj_BC_GSET , _lj_BC_JFUNCF , _lj_BC_MULNV , _lj_BC_KSHORT , _lj_BC_FUNCV , _lj_BC_MULVV , _lj_BC_SUBNV , _lj_BC_TNEW , _lj_BC_JFORL , _lj_BC_TGETR , _lj_BC_KCDATA , _lj_BC_CAT , _lj_BC_ITERL , _lj_BC_ISLE , _lj_BC_MODNV , _lj_BC_ISEQS , _lj_BC_RET1 , _lj_BC_LEN , _lj_BC_GGET , _lj_BC_ISLT , _lj_BC_DIVVV )
  "_PC", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_UP", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_tgetent", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_tgetflag", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_tgetnum", referenced from:
      __rl_get_screen_size in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_tgetstr", referenced from:
      __rl_init_terminal_io in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
  "_tgoto", referenced from:
      _update_line in libreadline.a(display.o)
  "_tputs", referenced from:
      __rl_backspace in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      _rl_ding in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_enable_meta_key in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_disable_meta_key in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_control_keypad in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      __rl_set_cursor in libreadline.a(terminal.o)
      _rl_redisplay in libreadline.a(display.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/luajit] Error 1
make[1]: *** [exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/CMakeFiles/luajit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/lib/libluajit.dylib (No such file or directory)
./install.sh: line 67: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
Installing common Lua packages
./install.sh: line 71: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 72: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 73: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
Installing core Torch packages
./install.sh: line 76: /Users/Definiter/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
```

I cannot find other ways to install Torch.